# DynamoDB conditional update by checking the attribute value length

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

One of the attributes in my DynamoDB table is a list called `REQUEST_IDS`, and I want to check the length of that list to see if it satisfies a condition (less than 10) before update the item. How can I refer to the array length in my ConditionExpression in nodejs? Is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the conditional operation `size` [(docs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Functions)

In your case: `ConditionExpression: 'size(REQIEST_IDS) < 10`